# ul li navigation - get parameter value from onclick

Tags: javascript

I have three navigation menu. Each menu has many parameters. After entering all the values I would like to save them. For every menu click i call "checkMyFunction()" and trying to save it in the localStorage. After finishing I have save button(which is not included here) to create a json file from localStorage.

My question is : For every menu click I would like to get the parameter value "val" which i am not getting, instead i get the whole path of file location. Could anyone suggest me? Thanks.

```js
function checkMyFunction(val) {
 alert(val);
 if (val === 'one') {
  one();
 }
 else if (val === 'two') {
  two();
 }
 else if (val === 'three') {
  three();
 }
 else 
 { 
  alert('not included yet');
 }
}
 
 
 
function one() {
  alert('this is function one related');
}


function two() {
  alert('this is function two related');
}


function three() {
  alert('this is function three related');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>function check</title>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript" name="localObjectSave" src="localObjectSave.js"></script>

<body >
 
 <ul class="nav-icon">
  <li><a href="first.html" onclick="checkMyFunction(this,'first');">First Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="second.html" onclick="checkMyFunction(this,'second');">Second Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="third.html" onclick="checkMyFunction(this,'third');">third Information</a></li>
 </ul>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since you pass two parameters to the event handler, `checkMyFunction(hyperlink,val)` ? Other ways are to use a data property on the link and ask that one: `data-val="first"` and `hyperlink.getAttribute('data-val');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as you have to do is to add a new "obj" parameter in the function, and update the conditions like "one" to "first".

```js
function checkMyFunction(obj, val) {
 alert(val);
 if (val === 'first') {
  one();
 }
 else if (val === 'second') {
  two();
 }
 else if (val === 'third') {
  three();
 }
 else 
 { 
  alert('not included yet');
 }
}
 
 
 
function one() {
  alert('this is function one related');
}


function two() {
  alert('this is function two related');
}


function three() {
  alert('this is function three related');
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-icon">
  <li><a href="first.html" onclick="checkMyFunction(this,'first');">First Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="second.html" onclick="checkMyFunction(this,'second');">Second Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="third.html" onclick="checkMyFunction(this,'third');">third Information</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because you are passing just one parameter and referencing the wrong argument in your code. Here's what will work.

```js
const checkMyFunction = (e, val) => {
 val === 'first' ? one() : val === 'second' ? two() : val === 'third' ? three() : alert('not included yet');
}

 
const one = () => {
  alert('this is function one related');
}


const two = () => {
  alert('this is function two related');
}


const three = () => {
  alert('this is function three related');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>function check</title>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript" name="localObjectSave" src="localObjectSave.js"></script>

<body >
 
 <ul class="nav-icon">
  <li><a href="first.html" onclick="checkMyFunction(this,'first');">First Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="second.html" onclick="checkMyFunction(this,'second');">Second Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="third.html" onclick="checkMyFunction(this,'third');">third Information</a></li>
 </ul>
 
</body>

</html>
```